# Why is my accuracy a constant number when training my siamese model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence, siamese-network

I am training a siamese model but my accuracy sometimes fall to a constant number. There are times where it trains fine, it'll give me an accuracy above 0.9 and it's not a constant number with every epoch. But sometimes it falls to a number between 0.5-0.6 and stays the same every epoch after.

```
anchor_input = Input((100, 100, 3), name = 'Anchor')
negative_input = Input((100, 100, 3), name = 'Negative')

embedding_network = Sequential(name = 'Embedding')
embedding_network.add(Conv2D(64, conv1, activation = 'relu', name = 'Conv1'))
embedding_network.add(MaxPooling2D(64, (2, 2), padding = 'same', name = 'Maxpool1'))
embedding_network.add(Conv2D(128, conv2, activation = 'relu', name = 'Conv2'))
embedding_network.add(MaxPooling2D(64, (2, 2), padding = 'same', name = 'Maxpool2'))
embedding_network.add(Conv2D(128, conv3, activation = 'relu', name = 'Conv3'))
embedding_network.add(MaxPooling2D(64, (2, 2), padding = 'same', name = 'Maxpool3'))
embedding_network.add(Conv2D(256, conv4, activation = 'relu', name = 'Conv4'))
embedding_network.add(Flatten(name = 'Flatten'))
embedding_network.add(Dense(4096, activation = 'sigmoid'))

anchor_embedding = embedding_network(anchor_input)
negative_embedding = embedding_network(negative_input)
distance = tf.math.abs(anchor_embedding - negative_embedding)
prediction = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(distance)

siamese_model = Model(inputs = [anchor_input, negative_input], outputs = prediction)
siamese_model.compile(loss = BinaryCrossentropy() , optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

Results:

Epoch 1/10
57/57 [==============================] - 17s 190ms/step - loss: 0.4081 - accuracy: 0.6702

Epoch 2/10
57/57 [==============================] - 11s 185ms/step - loss: 0.4000 - accuracy: 0.8598

Epoch 3/10
57/57 [==============================] - 10s 184ms/step - loss: 0.3117 - accuracy: 0.9972

Epoch 4/10
57/57 [==============================] - 10s 184ms/step - loss: 0.2975 - accuracy: 0.9994

Epoch 5/10
57/57 [==============================] - 10s 172ms/step - loss: 0.6899 - accuracy: 0.5078

Epoch 6/10
57/57 [==============================] - 10s 172ms/step - loss: 0.7003 - accuracy: 0.4917

Epoch 7/10
57/57 [==============================] - 10s 172ms/step - loss: 0.6992 - accuracy: 0.4917

Epoch 8/10
57/57 [==============================] - 10s 173ms/step - loss: 0.6983 - accuracy: 0.4917

Epoch 9/10
57/57 [==============================] - 10s 173ms/step - loss: 0.6975 - accuracy: 0.4917

Epoch 10/10
57/57 [==============================] - 10s 176ms/step - loss: 0.6967 - accuracy: 0.4917

As said, it's not always like this. Sometimes it trains fine. I haven't changed the data either.

Side note: I am using tf.data.Dataset to fit the model.

Things I've tried:

- Changed the loss from 'binary_crossentropy' to the class BinaryCrossentropy()
- Adjusting batch size/epochs
- Close the application then re-train it.
- Changed the data around (taking new pictures, prevent blurry pictures, stay in the same location)